# How do I know the generic object that the Observer class sends in Java?

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern

I am implementing the Observer / Observable pattern using Java.  However, I am encountering a problem in the Observer portion of my code.

**Observable**

```
public class Model extends Observable {

   public void notify() {
       this.setChanged();
       this.notifyObservers(new ArrayList<A>());
       this.notifyObservers(new ArrayList<B>());
   }
}
```

**Observer**

```
public class View implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object object) {
        // TODO: If object is ArrayList<A>?
        System.out.println("A");
        // TODO: If object is ArrayList<B>?
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

How would I fill in the TODO comments to check for the generic on the ArrayList?  Is this even possible?  (I would prefer to do it without implementing more classes, if possible.)

Comment: not sure this is possible because of erasure. You cannot tell the type during run time. See this on erasure http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Observable should send one and only one type of data.

```
public class ModelA extends Observable {

   public void notify() {
       this.setChanged();
       this.notifyObservers(new ArrayList<A>());
   }
}

public class ModelB extends Observable {

   public void notify() {
       this.setChanged();
       this.notifyObservers(new ArrayList<B>());
   }
}
```

Your other alternative is to put ArrayList<A> and ArrayList<B> into a class.  You can notify your observers with that class.

Comment: Thank you - I'll break my model up into better sub-divisions.  A side question: is it better to pass a controller as the object?

Comment: @sdasdadas: It depends on what you need.  I've been using the Listener model from Swing when I need an observer / observable pattern.  That way, I can decide what methods are needed in the equivalent of the observer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `instanceof` to see what type is your object but you are misusing the pattern.
The idea is that the `Observable` has a well defined interface and all the `Observer` needs to know is to use the API to pass the notification.
Logic to know what exactly *is* the `Observable` should not be mixed in the code.
From your question sounds to me you have 2 `Observable` and they should keep their own listeners *interested specifically in them* for notification. Not one combined

Comment: can you use instanceof? I dont think you can The array lists are typed and this information is lost. (I agree though on the misuse of the pattern)

Comment: Why does Java allow the passing of an Object to the observers?  What should I pass (if anything) in the object field?

Comment: @user846476:You are right. You can only see if `instanceof List`.He could check the elements if are `instanceof A` but even if he could he is missing the pattern

Comment: @sdasdadas:You can pass in a custom `Object` that your listeners knows how to cast back.Essentially is the notification object (has information related to the reason of the notification)